# Receive a notification of a new announcement on a page with flats to rent

Tags: javascript, notifications

I would like to write a program to observe a particular URL (with announcements about flats to rent) and get notified of any new announcement that meets my criteria. Is there a way to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: Check this website https://visualping.io/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can look through the page using something like 
[cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).Basically have a job that runs with a frequency.Identify changes in the page . Look for flags in the page or date changes to items and accordingly write a notifier service that will update you on those changes .